# Openjdk-7-jdk some commands not recognized?

Tags: java, openjdk

I installed openjdk-7-jdk using apt-get install. However, when I type 'javac', the terminal says, 'bash: /usr/bin/javac: No such file or directory'. I think the link is broken, but how can I fix it?

Note: I installed openjdk-7-jdk before, but then I removed openjdk and installed sun-java. Now I deleted sun-jdk and want to go back to openjdk, but javac is not recognized. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Edit: Recognized: java; Not Recognized: javac, javadoc, appletviewer, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following workaround worked for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac 1
```

Installing java on Ubuntu was much easier some years ago. I don't know why the hell the guys at Canonical make it more and more complex.

Comment: It is still easy, but if you follow some outdated blog on the internet and break it manually, it's your own fault...

Comment: Sorry, but I did not follow any outdated blog. I just installed the JDK with `apt-get install java7-jdk`.

Comment: Did you mean `openjdk-7-jdk`?

Comment: `aptitude show java7-jdk` tells `State: not a real package` and `Provided by: openjdk-7-jdk`. So, the answer is yes and no.

Comment: that looks like it works; I already reinstalled Ubuntu though